# Alternatives to event observer

Tags: java, events, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I am building an a application that uses the event observer pattern to allow points in the system to be extended easily by 3rd party vendors who wish to add their own functionality.

This works well however it relies on 1 thing:

- I must decide which points in the system vendors may wish to extend the system and trigger an event in that particular point in the flow.

It is entirely plausible that a vendor may wish to extend a different part of the system that I have not triggered an event from.

What are the alternatives here, to allow the vendor to extend the system from any point in the system they choose - or as close to that goal as possible - using something similar to event observer i.e. the can simply hook into the system where the choose to?

Comment: That’s a too broad question. Designing code to be as flexible/extensible as possible without an impractical fragmentation of the implementations is *the* challenge of good library design. That’s what all these OO mechanisms are about.

Comment: But i am looking something specifically like the event/observer pattern where external code can hook in based upon certain events.  Event either trigger based on the context, method calls etc.  But specifically something that doesnt require the main application to have to explicitly trigger an event

Comment: That sounds like “Aspect-oriented programming” to me. But I don’t see that as an alternative to events. It can not replace carefully designed extension points.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you need to do two things. The first is to go out and find some real clients, and talk to them. Where do they need extensions? They know that much better than you do. The second thing is to err on the side of not providing hooks. You can always add them later, but you will have to support anything that you put out, even if it's not used.

As @Holger said, there is no way to provide arbitrary hooks to any point in your system, and it's really not desirable for you to do so. That's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: the idea is that the vendors take the application and extend it in any way the need to.  But the main code provided remains untouched so they can benefit from future updates.  In that sense, the maintenance problem is their own.

Comment: @MartyWallace Believe me, if you intend to provide any kind of support at all, they will make it your problem. You will wind up breaking somebody's code with every minor release because users are relying on the prior behaviour of some remote corner of your codebase. Once you make something accessible to your users, you can be sure somebody's going to make it the Most Important Part Of Their Whole System.

Answer (score 0):

Holger mentioned already that AOP may help you. You simply annotate your code with your custom annotations and let your customers define their own aspects (they will be required to recompile the entire code base). For example:

```
@Data
public class Records {
  @Saving
  public void add(Record rec) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Later, your customer may say "I want to be triggered every time anyone is saving some data". He will have to define his own "aspect" with this custom "shortcut" (pseudo code):

```
@Aspect
public class OnSaving {
  @Before("execution(* @Data @Saving(..))")
  public void shortcut(JoinPoint pnt) {
    // your customer's code
  }
}
```

Your source code won't be changed, just recompiled. I assumed [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) usage.